# Android added fragment unable to show after back pressed

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

I have 3 fragment fragmentA, fragmentB, fragmentC that are added by default on the activity on create to keep it instance after that, I have another fragment fragmentX that to be added on the fragment container with backStack on Button click, the fragmentX is shown on add but when I need to show it again its not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityBaseClass {

private Fragment fragmentA;
private Fragment fragmentB;
private Fragment fragmentC;
private Fragment fragmentX;

@BindView(R.id.btn_show_fragmentx)
Button mBtnShowFragmentX;
@BindView(R.id.tab_layout)
TabLayout mTab;

private FragmentTransaction transaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    fragmentA = FragmentA.newInstance();
    fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();
    fragmentC = FragmentC.newInstance();

    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentA, "A");
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB, "B");
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentC, "C");
    transaction.commit();


    mTab.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    transaction.show(fragmentA);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentB);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentC);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    transaction.show(fragmentB);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentA);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentC);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    transaction.show(fragmentC);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentA);
                    transaction.hide(fragmentB);
                    break;

            }
            transaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_show_fragmentx)
public void showFragmentX() {
    if (fragmentX == null) {
        fragmentX = FragmentX.newInstance();
        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentX, "X");
        transaction.addToBackStack("X");
        transaction.commit();
    } else {
        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.show(fragmentX);
        transaction.addToBackStack("X");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.hide(fragment);
        transaction.commit();

         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if the fragmentX is null then I initialized it on the if statement before I added to the transaction. and I need to keep track of the fragment for handling the back press button click so I don't need to remove the addToBackStack function

Comment: add `.addToBackStack(null)` should work

Comment: adding the fragment works fine but when I need to show it again and the fragment is not null I just need to show  it again on the else condition.

Comment: When you backstack the fragment will remove from the  stack. if you want to show this again you have to add the fragment again in the backstack

Comment: You should use `ViewPager` for using fragments with tabs

Answer (score 0):

You fragmentX is destroyed when `onBackPressed` is called. You need to check for the backstack's current fragment, if it is an instance of FragmentX, then hide it (and don't pop the backstack), otherwise do your code.